# Apache CXF WSDLToJava Error: operation already exists. How to bypass?

Tags: wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I am developing second client application that is consuming existing SOAP web-services.
I generate Java from existing WSDL using the latest Apache CXF 2.3 tool

wsdl2java -client -ant http://172.20.0.22/someletters/TradingServer.asmx?WSDL

and get

WSDLToJava Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An operation with name [{urn:someschema:TradingServer}GetTradeSummary] already exists in this service

that has logic, because when looking at WSDL file you can see 2 similar operation GetTradeSummary, but with different soapAction.

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetTradeSummary">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:someschema/GetTradeSummary" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetTradeSummary">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:someschema/GetTradeSummary_Open" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input name="GetTradeSummary_Open">
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="GetTradeSummary_Open">
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

a) Is it really regarded as erroneous by some standard? Which one?

b) Is there way to bypass this and generate Java scaffolding for the rest?
There's nothing such mentioned at [CXF WSDL to Java tool web page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html), except -autoNameResolution which does not help.

Comment: http://www.apacheserver.net/the-Apache-CXF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specifically disallowed by the WSI-Basic Profile.  If you look at:

http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1.html

Section 4.5.3, it specifically states:

Operation name overloading in a wsdl:portType is disallowed by the Profile.

I don't think there is a way around it in CXF as the operations are stored in a Map keyed on QName.   Since the QNames would not be unique, only one operation can be stored in the map.

Comment: So is there way for b), that is to skip second erroneous occurrence and continue to generate code?

Comment: Can't you simply remove the operation element from the wsdl before you generate?